# Declare angular controller without making it global, but getting its functions listed in the visual studio function selector

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio

I have a web application with many angular controllers, services and directives.

Currently I declare all the controllers like this:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("myController", function ($scope, myService)
{
    $scope.something = function()
    {

    }

});
```

Using this method, visual studio doesn't show `$scope.something` as a function in the helper dropdown at the top, where you normally get a list of all the functions and a way to navigate to them quickly.

If I declare my controller like this however, I get all my functions listed:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("myController", ["$scope", "myService", myController]);

function myController($scope, myService)
{
    $scope.something = function()
    {

    }

};
```

However with this method my controller function is Global and I don't like this. Is there a way to get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a self-invoking function:

```
(function(angular){
'use strict';
angular.module("myApp").controller("myController", ["$scope", "myService", myController]);

function myController($scope, myService)
{
    $scope.something = function()
    {

    }

};

})(angular);
```

You probably won't need to pass in angular though, since it is global.

But anyway, this way `myController` won't be global.

Comment: Aha, thank you. I had something like this, but I was missing the final part `(angular)`. Can you explain what this does?

Comment: It passes `angular` as the first argument to the self-invoking function.

`(function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
      // arg1 == angular
      // arg2 == jquery
      // arg3 == whatever
    }) (angular, jquery, whatever);`
Altho `angular` is _global_ I would recommend using this pattern -- it also helps when minimizing the javascript.

Comment: @Neil, see null's explanation.